# Google Analytics 4 Measurement Protocol/Postman POST Request 403 Error

Tags: postman, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm attempting to send a `POST` request to my Google Analytics 4 property directly from Postman. My current request looks like so:

[image]

However, when I attempt to send this request I am met with the following output:

```
<a href=//www.google.com/> <span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
<p><b>403.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
    <p>Your client does not have permission to get URL
        <code>/mp/collect?measurement_id=G-xxxxx&amp;api_secret=_xxxxxx</code> from this server.
        <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

I'm currently referencing [this documentation provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/sending-events?client_type=gtag).

Any idea how/why this could be happening? I triple-checked my secret/measurement ids.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but this was because I had disabled the `host` header. You might want to check the headers tab to see if you have enabled the host header. If you don't see the default headers in that tab, click on [the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84tat.png) to show the default headers.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue, but was trying it from C# code. I also test on postman and it returned 403. What worked for me was putting `https://` before the `www.google-analytics.com`